# Define additional shortkey with the same effect like RETURN in Safari.app

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, keybindings, quicksilver

I'm working with MacOS X 10.6.

I'd like to define a keyboard shortcut `Ctrl-m`, which does the same thing like `RETURN` does, without deactivating `RETURN`.

How can I do that in `MacOS X 10.6`. In the keyboard control panel, I can only assign menu commands to shortcuts, but RETURN is not a menu command, but a key that does different things in different locations.

How can I do that?

---

*Remark:*

- I would prefer a built-in or at least free solution. I'm using [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com) already, so if it would be able to define such a key/trigger, that would also be helpful.
- *If you wonder, why I want to do it, you'll find the explanation here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3544/is-there-a-more-convenient-key-binding-for-return*

Comment: I use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) for that kind of things.

Comment: Thanks! Well, I'd like to avoid paying 42$ just for changing a few keybindings, which (I'd assume) should also be possible with some "hacking", shouldn't it? Anyway, are you sure `Keyboard Maestro` would be able to create such a shortkey which has the same effect like RETURN in Safari?

Comment: Pretty sure. I posted an answer with an image of a macro that do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible using Quicksilver to run an AppleScript that “types” Return, but that will probably be unreliable in some contexts.

A much more straightforward solution that doesn’t require any third-party tools is to just use the built-in key bindings system.

Add this to `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
    "^m" = "insertNewline:";
}
```

Things to be aware of:

1. That file doesn’t exist by default. You’ll need to create it.
2. This won’t apply to any applications that are already running. Relaunch the ones you want to use it in, or just log out and back in.
3. This only works in proper Cocoa applications. Cross-platform stuff like Firefox and MS Office won’t respect these key bindings.
4. More detail on the built-in key binding system can be found at http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/System%20Bindings.html

Comment: Hi Rob! Thanks a lot! AppleScripts are relatively slow from my experience, so I'd prefer the key-binding solution. Thanks a lot for the very useful hint on "proper Cocoa apps"!! Question: how can I find out, if an application is "proper Cocoa"?

Comment: p.s. is there a way to find out, if that key-binding (e. g. `^m` is already used/defined in other applications?

Comment: I don’t know of a sure-fire way to tell if something is Cocoa other than checking with the developer. Inconsistent appearance is the biggest clue.

As for figuring out where it’s used, you’ll just have to look around at the menus or try pressing it in different apps to see what happens. I would hope that a standard on like ⌃M isn’t used anywhere (unless it’s already used as Return).